# Can't create list from loop output float

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, floating-point

I need to take a loop's output float values and put them into a list or DataFrame for further use.

The current code I'm using:

```
for m in range(1, 10):
    M=[]
    M.append(1/m)
    print(M)

    [0.5]  
    [0.3333333333333333]  
    [0.25]  
    [0.2]  
    [0.16666666666666666]  
    [0.14285714285714285]  
    [0.125]  
    [0.1111111111111111]
```

Expected result:

```
[1.0, 0.5, 0.3333333333333333, 0.25, 0.2, 0.16666666666666666, 0.14285714285714285, 0.125, 0.1111111111111111]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `my_list = []`, and then replace your current loop with

```
for m in range(1, 10):
    my_list.append(1/m)
```

Then, use `print(my_list)`, so it looks like this:

```py
my_list = []
for m in range(1, 10):
    my_list.append(1/m)
print(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create M outside the loop, otherwise it will be overwritten for every iteration

```
M=[]
for m in range(1, 10):
    M.append(1/m)
print(M)
```